# Keeping C# and C++ classes in sync at runtime?

Tags: c#, c++, synchronization

My application is built in two sections. A C# executable which is the front end UI and a C++ dll which is more the low-level stuff. My application creates and manages many instances of objects, where every C++ object instance has a corresponding C# object instance. What techniques or libraries can I use to ensure that objects in the C# and C++ sections and data in those objects are always in sync at runtime? A change of one member in one object instance should update the corresponding object instance.

Thanks!

Edit: clarified a little what I meant by keeping the objects in "sync"

Comment: Does the C# object instance encapsulate the C++ object instance? Is it a case where for example, your C# object would contain a pointer to the C++ object?

Comment: They're independent. They would communicate through an intermediate object, like through a network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear whether it would solve the problem, but have you considered Managed C++? I have had pretty good success simply compiling my C++ code as Managed C++, then using the managed extensions to create .NET classes that use the underlying C++ data directly. That way, there's only one copy of the data.

Probably not suitable for every situation (and I haven't tested its limits by any means) but I found it quite a timesaver. And since Managed C++ is a proper .NET language, the result was clean to use from the C# side, with none of the usual oddities or quirks one often has to work around when trying this sort of thing.

(Another similar approach would be to use SWIG (http://www.swig.org/) to generate wrappers for you. I hear it is easy to use and works well, but I haven't used it myself.)

Comment: Hi brone! Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, the design is out of my hands. I'm just looking for the best solution taking into account the current design.

Comment: however, had I the choice I'd probably pick a solution exactly like this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps code-generation would work well.  E.g. define the properties/methods for these classes in one spot (maybe XML or something) and generate C# and C++ classes from that.  Perhaps use something like CodeSmith (http://www.codesmithtools.com/) to generate your code.

Comment: When you do that, make sure the C# classes you generate are 'partial'.  That way, if you have to add any UI specific code to the C# class, you don't have to regenerate the object, and doing so doesn't prevent the regeneration of the object either.

Comment: Hi Alex! I realized I didn't specify exactly in what way those objects should stay in sync, so I updated my question. What I meant was to keep instances in sync at run time. Thanks!